# Java GUI froze after choice

Tags: java, user-interface, jpanel, refresh, freeze

I'm trying to modify a code not written by me.

I need to insert a Jpane that requires a confirmation by the User who wants to add a condominium.

```
public class InserireNuovoCondominio extends javax.swing.JFrame implements BaseBoundary, 
                                                                       WindowListener,
                                                                       TableModelListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// Graphics variables declaration - do not modify
public javax.swing.JButton jButtonAnnulla;
public javax.swing.JButton jButtonConferma;
public javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBoxCom;
public javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBoxProv;
public javax.swing.JLabel jLabelCAP;
public javax.swing.JLabel jLabelComune;
public javax.swing.JLabel jLabelId;
public javax.swing.JLabel jLabelProv;
public javax.swing.JLabel jLabelSlash;
public javax.swing.JLabel jLabelVia;
public javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldCAP;
public javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldId;
public javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldInterno;
public javax.swing.JTextField jTextFieldVia;
// End of graphics variables declaration

private UnitaImmobiliari unitaImmobiliari = new UnitaImmobiliari();
private DatiCondominio datiCondominio = new DatiCondominio();
private Millesimi tabellaGenerale = new Millesimi();

public DatiCondominio my_dati_gen = new DatiCondominio();
```

Here in this method:

```
    public InserireNuovoCondominio(){
    super();
    StatoCorrente = START;
    int risp = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,"Vuoi veramente inserire un nuovo Condominio",     "Conferma Inserimento Condominio", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(risp == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
    initComponents();
    }

}
```

If I reply with a YES_OPTION the program works fine, but I really don't know what put in the NO_Option, I made a few tries but the program freeze and I need to restart Eclipse.

Is there a method to refresh the GUI ?

Thanks for the help.
Best regards.

Comment: to refresh the gui, you can use revalidate() method.

Comment: in NO_OPTION you can write close() ?

Comment: A constructor is not a good place for asking the user for a decision that may result in the object not being built as it should be. The dialog should guard the place where the constructor is called; then the NO_OPTION should result in bypassing the object construction, not adding a new Condo to the assembly.

Comment: Hi, I've solved putting the "choice" where the constructor is called as laune suggested.

It worked as well with the Yes_Option alone, NO_Option was not required.

close( ) and revalidate ( ) inside the constructor both don't work.